# Erro ao compartilhar tela via Navegador (Chrome e Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webrtc

Estou tentando fazer com que o diálogo de Compartilhamento de Tela apareça no Chrome, mas nada acontece.

Estou usando o seguinte código (Apenas para exibir o diálogo, vou passar a stream para o servidor quando funcionar)

```
    function screenshare() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'screen',
                maxWidth: 1920,
                maxHeight: 1080,
                minAspectRatio: 1.77
            }
        },
        audio: false
    }, function(stream) {
        console.log(stream)
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Quando eu executo a função eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
NavigatorUserMediaError {name: "InvalidStateError", message: "", constraintName: ""}constraintName: ""message: ""name: "InvalidStateError"__proto__: NavigatorUserMediaError
```

Sim, já estou com extensão configurada e instalada no Chrome.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Obrigado!